# How to use Git in GoLand

Tags: git, goland

If there are two branches in a project, one is the main branch and the other is my own branch, I have cloned the code to the local ide. If the main branch is modified, what should I do to synchronize the modified code to my branch and make changes on the local ide?

Comment: This appears to be a question about how to work your IDE, rather than about how to use Git. As such, you'll need to specify the IDE involved.

Comment: The IDE used is Goland.

Comment: On the other hand, it could be a general question about Git that has nothing to do with the specific IDE used. The current answer answered that question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. I know some:

- `rebase`: rebase your branch to the main branch
- `merge`: merge your branch to the main branch

All above will be possible to cause conflicts, just solve them.